# Quiero que el bucle empieze de 1 a 100

Tags: javascript

Tengo una grid de 10 * 10 donde al pasar el cursor muestra el número del 1 al 100 por cada cuadro, el problema  es que al crear un bucle de 1 al 100 no me reconoce 01 y empieza de 00 al 99? Solo quiero que cuando muestre el número empiece de 1 al 100.

```js
//SELECT MENU LIBRARY
const contentOfCard = document.querySelector('.card-content');

let createContentOfCard = (()=> {
 for(let i = 1;i<=100;i++){
  let card = document.createElement('div');
  card.classList.add(`card-${i}`);
  contentOfCard.appendChild(card);
  loadImage(card);
 }
});
  

let loadImage = ((card) => {
  const pruebaCard = document.querySelector('.card-50');
  if (card == pruebaCard) {
    const cardData = document.createElement('div');
    cardData.classList.add('card-data');
    pruebaCard.appendChild(cardData);
 }
});
  

createContentOfCard();

var selectCard = document.getElementById('selectCard').children;

const txt = document.querySelector('.txt');

/*Quiero que selecciones del 1 al 100
pero empieza de 2 en el cuadro al 99*/
for (let i = 1;i< 100; i++) {
  selectCard[i].addEventListener('mousemove', () => {
   txt.innerHTML = `<p>0${i}</p>`;
  });
  txt.innerHTML = `<p>0${i}</p>`;
}
```

```css
/*-----------------------------*\
     $SETTING
\*-----------------------------*/

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/*-----------------------------*\
     $COLORS
\*-----------------------------*/

$color_black: #000000;
$color_green: #2dd122;
$color_purple: #778cff;
$color_blue: #0d50a1;
$color_white: #ffffff;
/*-----------------------------*\
     $FONTS
\*-----------------------------*/

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:wght@300&display=swap');
$fontFamily: "Nunito", sans-serif;
$fontLight: 300;
/*-----------------------------*\
     $GRID
\*-----------------------------*/

$widthContent: 100%;
$maxWdith: 320px;


body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background: $color_black;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: $fontFamily;
  font-weight: $fontLight;
}

.card-container {
  h1 {
    color: $color_white;
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
  }

  .card-content {
    width: $widthContent;
    max-width: $maxWdith;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(10, 1fr);
    border: 10px solid transparent;
    border-image: radial-gradient(circle, rgba(148, 143, 140, 1) 0%, rgba(78, 76, 69, 1) 39%, rgba(148, 143, 140, 1) 100%) 1;
    @for $i from 0 through 100 {
      .card-#{$i} {
        width: 30px;
        height: 40px;
        border: 1px solid #676665b3;
        box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px;
      }
    }
  }

  .txt {
    width: $widthContent;
    max-width: $maxWdith;
    background-color: #919190;
    color: $color_white;
    padding: 10px;

    p {
      background: #101009;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 4px;
    }

    h3 {
      background: #101009;
      padding: 10px;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="card-container">
  <h1>&lt; 9/100 &gt;</h1>
  <div class="card-content" id="selectCard"></div>
  <div class="txt"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Recuerda que las posiciones de los Array empiezan por el 0, no el 1. Así que efectivamente la posición 1 apunta al segundo valor. Así que el bucle debe ir del 0 al 99.

Comment: Gracias, lo resolvi creando const num = i + 1; dentro del bucle ;) de esta manera no rompo el bucle de 0 a 99 T.T

Comment: Si resolviste tu problema, te invito a contestar la solución en tu pregunta (se puede y es normal hacerlo) así más pérsonas pueden usar tu experiencia para resolver un problema parecido. Saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Cómo solucioné el problema:

```
    //Solución del problema
    for (let i = 0;i< 100; i++) {
     //Le sumo 1 a i
      let num = i + 1;
      selectCard[num].addEventListener('mousemove', () => {
       txt.innerHTML = `<p>0${num}</p>`;
      });
      txt.innerHTML = `<p>0${num}</p>`;
    }
```

Comment: Solo a modo de recordatorio: cuando se cumpla el tiempo, recuerda [aceptar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) tu propia respuesta, ya que [el usuario "Comunidad" se encarga de revivir la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1215/qu%c3%a9-sucede-con-las-preguntas-que-tienen-respuestas-validas-pero-no-son-marcadas/1452) cada cierto tiempo.